# Calling Soap with Header and body in php

Tags: php, soap

I need to send a soap request with soap header and body.
I have the request soap xml.
I had use different curl and soap client but nothing is working.
Some one please help.

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v2="http://www.v.com/schema/" xmlns:loc="http://www.c.org/local">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <RequestSOAPHeader xmlns="http://www.h.com/schema/1">
         <s1>000201</s1>
         <s2>e6434ef249df55c7a21a0b45758a39bb</s2>
         <s3>35000001000001</s3>
         <s4>20100731064245</s4>
      </RequestSOAPHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <loc:start>
         <loc:reference>
            <c1>http://desertcreator.com/nct</c1>
            <c2>notify</c2>
            <c3>1</c3>
         </loc:reference>
         <loc:w1>1234</loc:w1>
         <loc:w2>demand</loc:w2>
      </loc:start>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your SOAP Header is not well formed. `<s2>` element is not closed properly. You closed it with `</s1>` tag. Change it to `</s2>` and try again.

Comment: I need the php code how to call it..
It was an mistake..
can u pls help..

Comment: Check [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) for calling a web service using PHP.